# Apache 2.2 statistics?

Tags: apache-2.2

I've been wondering if there is a way to get apache statistics?
I'm looking for something that can show graphs and inform me what's the traffic at certain hours, how is the server performing during those hours and etc.
I tried the default Apache Server Status but it didn't fit my needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can give a try to [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/). It supports more than just Apache monitoring and is extendable with plugins.

If you need to know detailed informations about your visitors you can also take a look at [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: I second awstats.  I use it myself, and it gives some good statistics.